# Wordpress category check

Tags: categories

So I have a plugin, and i want to have a multiselect drop-down list with all categories in widget's settings and store (by admin's choice) selected ones (ids).

[image]

Then to check if we are viewing a post "is_single()" and the post has some of the above selected categories "in_category("3") (say we chose cat:Logo with id:3):

```
if(is_single() && in_category("3")){//do my thing}
```

and ofcourse if user chose more than 1, say (3,5,6 cat ids(by their names click))
the codition would be something like:

```
if(is_single() && in_category($categoryholderfromdb)){//do my thing}
```

Where $categoryholderfromdb="3,5,6" (stored user choices in db (widget settings drop-down))

i've tried to do it, but i can't figure out the part with drop-down multiselect and then "in_category" when checking for multy values.

Can anyone give me example of the above question?Thanks!

Comment: What plugin are you using for the multiselect? And how does it store the data for the post?

Comment: The idea is to create one function like this one (in the image) i want to create my own. That's the hard part of the question, i need similar working script...

Comment: Well that's much a bigger question, and outside the scope of this one. Have you tried the WordPress codex/Google/WPSE for advice on creating metaboxes and saving data? Or the much easier alternative [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin?

Comment: I've already developed the widget, i just need the multiselect box and the "in_category" codition that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You want the function [`in_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category), not `in_cat()`. And to check multiple categories you need to pass an array as a single argument (as opposed to multiple  arguments):

```
if ( is_single() && in_category( array( 3, 5, 6 ) ) )
```

Comment: yeah i know it is is_category i've just mispelled it. The idea is to have the cats in multiselect and then retrive them into an array maby? and then to  use it in tha bove example. I've edited my question, please take another look. Thanks